# ColdFusion : Android strings.xml file functionality

Tags: coldfusion

I was wondering if there is any strings centralization in ColdFusion similar to Android strings.xml file.
So, that my code remains intact if i want to do any changes in string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ColdFusion is a programming language, not a user interface framework.

There is nothing like Android's string resource management built into ColdFusion, but it would be very easy to implement that yourself.

`resources/strings.xml`:

```
<!-- keep as a structure with unique element names -->
<strings>
  <heading>This is a test.</heading>
  <greetings>
    <hello>Hello World!</hello>
    <bye>Goodbye World!</bye>
  </greetings>
</strings>
```

ColdFusion utility function (for example in a CFC component `util.cfc`):

```
<cffunction name="ReadResouceXml" returntype="struct" access="public" output="no">
  <cfargument name="path"   type="string" required="yes">
  <!--- internal use argument --->
  <cfargument name="xmlDoc" type="xml"    required="no">

  <cfset var xmlElem = "">
  <cfset var output  = StructNew()>

  <!--- read XML file from disk --->
  <cfif not StructKeyExists(arguments, "xmlDoc")>
    <cffile action="read" file="#ExpandPath(path)#" variable="xmlDoc" charset="UTF-8">
    <cfset xmlDoc = XmlParse(xmlDoc).XmlRoot>
  </cfif>      

  <!--- recursively convert XML to a CF struct --->
  <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(xmlDoc.XmlChildren)#">
    <cfset xmlElem = xmlDoc.XmlChildren[i]>
    <cfif ArrayLen(xmlElem.XmlChildren) gt 0>
      <cfset output[xmlElem.XmlName] = ReadResouceXml("", xmlElem)>
    <cfelse>
      <cfset output[xmlElem.XmlName] = xmlElem.XmlText>
    </cfif>
  </cfloop>
  <cfreturn output>
</cffunction>
```

Coldfusion usage:

```
<cfobject type="component" name="util" component="util">
<cfset strings = util.ReadResouceXml("resources/strings.xml")>

<cfoutput>
<h1>#strings.heading#</h1>
#strings.greetings.hello# - #strings.greetings.bye#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks. This will implement the same thing as Android but in little complicated way. As ColdFusion doesn't supports it. There is one correction in the function. It's working fine now.

Comment: @Sonam This is *seven* lines of ColdFusion code to implement a string resource management system. If you find this "complicated" I'm not sure what you do when you face real problems.

Comment: Actually it worked. Cool Thanks. Actually my words were not correct. Sorry for that. I have faced many situations complicated than that. Just used wrong words.

Comment: @Sonam What's the correction? (I can't find the error - you can edit my answer and fix the code).

Comment: I have corrected the error. It was jus a minute mistake. action="read" was not there in function.

Comment: @Sonam Ah, you're right. I thought `action = "read"` was the default, just like it is with `<cfdirectory>`. Thanks.

Comment: @sonam Note that my answer contained a severe mistake. Using the XML file directly is wrong, we must convert it to a structure first (or ColdFusion will output XML instead of strings). See revised answer. I admit, it's not 7 lines anymore, but it's still pretty short & usage is the same.

Comment: Oh got it. It was returning xml file. Performance wise its not good. Thanks for suggesting the best idea.

Comment: @sonam What do you mean by "Performance wise its not good"? This should be plenty fast. Do you have any measurements/timings? Where do you experience problems?

Comment: Previous one would not be fast as we were returning xml file. This would be fast as time needed to access structure is much less. No, i have no such measurement. I am saying conceptual wise.

Comment: @sonam It's always best to make some measurements. Don't make statements about performance because of a gut feeling. Also note that I've made another (and hopefully last) change to the function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14068/discussion-between-sonam-and-tomalak)